# Compare each row in a table with all the rows in other table in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a scenario to validate each row in **Table 1** with all the conditions in **Table 2** to make a decision whether to approve or reject a request in power Query, Is it possible?

Please refer to the sample tables below

**Table 1**

```
  Users   Start Date    End Date    Fully paid   Decision
     A     1/1/2021     5/1/2021  
     B     1/2/2021     5/2/2021          No
     C                  5/3/2021          Yes
     D     1/4/2021                       No
     E     1/5/2021     5/5/2021          Yes
     F                  5/6/2021          No
```

**Table 2**

```
Conditions                                                           Decision
If start date and end date are not null                               Approve
If start date and end date are null but fully paid is Yes             Approve
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Quick response!, This is a static way of applying conditions. If the condition changes, we need to change the condition manually in the query. I was looking for a little more dynamic solution, something like directly referring to the conditions from the second table.

If some conditions needs to be changed, the conditions are applied automatically and decisions are made when the query is refreshed.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Your table 2 does not make sense because if you apply them in sequence, then step 1 would mean that step 2 is never exectu

Comment: Agree, The above sample tables may not make the real sense but the objective is to evaluate a user (each row in table A) with multiple criteria (conditions in table B) more dynamically. Example scenario to express the idea: Applying for a Driving License. Consider Table 1 as user information and table 2 as DMV requirements. Table 2 can have criteria like Provide conditions: 1.SSN or Passport - approve 2.No SSN but Bank statement and paystubs - approve . 3 No SSN and No Passport and No Paystubs - reject.  Hope you understand the problem I'm trying to solve

Comment: I mean, if the user meets the condition and get approved status, we don't need to check for the remaining conditions. Ignore the "reject" conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done - I have done that in the past - my use case was to create dynamic definitions of new columns in Excel with complex conditions.

It comes down to translating your rows to if / else statenements dynamically using `M`. One you've done that (and it takes some time do do that - you need to employ recursion to process entire list and output a single string with all conditions), all you have to do is `Expression.Evaluate` your string.

So in short, you need to have entire `Table.AddColumn` command created as string dynamically.

Comment: Hello! 

I’m glad that you have tried this scenario before, I was trying few ways and was looking for ideas. I’m new to the recursion functions in the M language, it would be great if you could write the syntax to validate one row in table 1 with all the conditions in table 2 dynamically. Meanwhile I’ll try few list functions like List.matchall, List.matchany etc..

Comment: I mean, if the user meets the condition and get approved status, we don't need to check for the remaining conditions. Ignore the "reject" conditions.